# UsageStatsManager is not working in android 11 with permission of PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS

Tags: java, android, kotlin, accessibilityservice

my application is working perfectly for 10 and lower versions of android. I have checked the documentation they said something changed about usage stats functionality(i.e https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-all#app-usage-stats) Any help?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of struggle I have got the solution for my problem. Actually
`context.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);`  Should return the list of all the installed apps but in android 11 it'll only return the list of system apps. To get the list of all the applications(system+user) we need to provide an additional permission to the application i.e

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES">